# Convert blob object into base64 javascript

Tags: javascript, base64, filereader, filesaver.js

I am trying to convert blob object into base64

```
var out = doc.getZip().generate({
type: "blob",
mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
}) //Output the document using Data-URI
```

In the below console. I am getting blob object.

```
console.log(Blob {size: 1402, type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'});
```

I used the blob object to convert into base64

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(out); 
reader.onloadend = function() {
var base64data = reader.result;                
console.log(base64data);
return;
}
```

but I am getting issue while converting into base64

> Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.

I used filesaver.js to allow me to download the file successfully by using saveAs() method

```
saveAs(out,"Details.docx");
```

Comment: `console.log(Blob {size: 1402, type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'});` isn't valid javascript, so ... not sure how you can be getting a blob object logged to the console

Comment: when I console them out variable. I get this  "Blob {size: 1402, type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'} "

Comment: no, that code you posted is not valid ... are you showing the result of console.log rather than the actual code?

Comment: I am showing the result of the console.log value

Comment: I realise that now - but it looks like invalid code :p

Comment: By using this block of code "saveAs(out, "Details.docx"); " I successfully downloaded the docx file

Comment: I need to call the downloaded file into the backend code to save in the s3 bucket. just why I am converting into base64 to calls to the backend method

Comment: Please show the whole script, not just separated snippets like that . The problem is probably a closure one and `out` isn't the same thing when you pass it to `readAsDataURL` than when you logged it.

Answer (score -1):

You wanna convert a docx to base64 as I understand

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="upload-button" class="fpd-btn-raised fpd-secondary-bg-color fpd-secondary-text-color">
  <i class="fpd-icon-file-upload"></i><span>Select File</span>
</div>
<input type="file" id="upload-file" class="btn btn-success" style="display:none;" />
<img src="" height="200" />
```

JS

```
$('#upload-button').click(function(){
  $('#upload-file').trigger('click');                 
  return false;
});

function convert(e) {
  if(window.FileReader) {
    var file  = e.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    reader.onloadend = function (e) {
      console.log(reader.result);
    }
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById('upload-file').addEventListener('change', convert, false);
  
});
```

Pen
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/fkeler/pen/JjLJLZp?editors=1111)